# Persisting dynamically generated html pages

Tags: java, html, eclipse, tomcat, put

With reference to that question: [PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest) I was trying to generate a dynamic HTML page using a servlet's put method. I was able to  generated the file (let's call it new_resource.html) using the classic FileOutputStream and place it in tomcat's deployment folder. new_resource.html becomes immediately reachable through HTTP which indicated that all is good.
Problem is that once eclipse is closed and reopened the file disappears possibly because eclipse is performing project cleaning which I believe would remove any "*foreign*" resource. 
What am I doing wrong and how can I persist this new resource and protect it from being deleted?
Is this the right way to generate new resources?
Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: eclipse usually does not clear the app except if you tell it to do so. Or in every new deployment.